# Don't trigger the Jquery event after a button has been pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've been trying to make this event where if you hover with your mouse near the back button, this div will show up a message saying "Where are you going? :(". I've got it working, but after some time, it becomes annoying.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="leaveModal dontgo">
    <h1>Where are you going? :(</h1>
    <div class="closebutton">
        <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("body").on("mousemove",function(event){
    if (event.pageX < 100 && event.pageY < 50) {
        $(".dontgo").fadeIn(600);
    }
}

/* Close Button */

$(".fa-times").click(function(){
    $(".dontgo").fadeOut(500);
})
```

Whenever I press the close button it closes, but it'll keep triggering the event. When I move towards my back button it becomes quite annoying for people.

Does anyone know how to make it not trigger the jQuery event after pressing the close button once?

Comment: you could create a bool var that you set to true after fadeOut and check for it in the `mousemove` function

Comment: Personally the whole function seems pointless and a little annoying -- even if it runs only once.

Comment: If a user chooses to close the hover popup, should it ever be executable again?

Comment: yes @War10ck, the shouldn't execute anymore if a user chose to close the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("body").off` could damage other trigger events ! So `remove` is optional for this.

```
$(".fa-times").click(function(){
    $(".dontgo").fadeOut(500).remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What about turning off the `body` listener when the button is clicked?

```
$(".fa-times").click(function(){
    $("body").off("mousemove");  //Turn off the listener for body
    $(".dontgo").fadeOut(500);
})
```

**EDIT:** As [war10ck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680836/war10ck) mentioned in the comments on this answer, the `$("body").off();` portion of the snippet above will remove all events bound to your `body`. I've edited my answer to instead say `$("body").off("mousemove");`, which will remove *only* the mousemove event.

Comment: Be advised that using `.off()` like this will unbind ***every*** event from the body element. You'd be better off just removing `mousemove` by calling `.off('mousemove');` and even better by namespacing the event and removing only your instance such as `.off('mousemover.hoverbox')`...

Comment: Correct. Given the example at hand I did not see this as an issue but I agree that it's an important note if using this method. I'll edit my answer to include your information.

Comment: Thanks Tyler! It works and I've got a related question. I've been making an email subscription popup, but as most popup work, they won't show up after you've subscribed. I believe this works with cookies, although I have no idea how to work that out. I've tried the JQuery cookie plugin and other ways, but never came to a solution.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) I believe you are on the right path in regards to cookies, however I wouldn't consider myself an expert in regards to them by any means. If I'm not mistaken, cookies must be set prior to the response headers of a page and so I'm not exactly sure how they would work via javascript. But again, I'm not familiar with Javascript + Cookies.